# TIFF2PDF Conversions Not Loading in PDF.js-based Viewers

Tags: pdf, firefox, pdf.js, libtiff, tiff2pdf

I am using Tiff2Pdf to perform conversions of TIFF files to PDFs. The PDFs load fine in Chrome and Edge's default PDF viewer as well as Adobe Acrobat Reader, though they take some time to load. However, in Firefox, which uses PDF.js and with the library `react-pdf` (https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf) the files fail to load. Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

I install it by doing `sudo apt install libtiff-tools` in my Linux VM.

I use the following command to convert the files: `tiff2pdf -o converted.pdf input.tiff`

The error associated with loading a local converted PDF file in the console is:

```
Partitioned cookie or storage access was provided to “file:///C:/Users/path/to/converted.pdf” because it is loaded in the third-party context and dynamic state partitioning is enabled.

Warning: Invalid absolute docBaseUrl: "file:///C:/Users/path/to/converted.pdf".

PDF <sequence of alphanumeric values> [1.1 libtiff / tiff2pdf - 20201219 / prt2tiff 2015-02-12] (PDF.js: 3.5.35 [5d15b0f69])

Warning: Unable to decode image "img_p0_1": "InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable".

Warning: Dependent image isn't ready yet

Warning: Unable to decode image "img_p1_1": "InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable".

Warning: Dependent image isn't ready yet
```